# Python Anywhere cannot find module

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

I cannot seem to Import From x import y a module in a subdirectory in Python Anywhere.

My app structure is as follows:

Home path:

```
app.py
Index.py
```

apps path - a subdirectory contained within my Home directory:

```
__init__.py (Blank init file)
Visualize.py
```

in my Index.py file I am attempting:

```
from apps import Visualize.py
```

I am getting a syntax error,

I have then changed it to test:

```
from . import apps
```

and it accepts this but I cannot reach my Visualize.py - any ideas why?

Further information on my wsgi.py - Directory and start:

```
# add your project directory to the sys.path
project_home = '/home/UserName/UserApp/'
if project_home not in sys.path:
    sys.path = [project_home] + sys.path

# import flask app but need to call it "application" for WSGI to work
from Index import app
application = app.server
```

Answer (score 0):

`from apps import Visualize.py` is not how you import from a file called `Visualize.py`. You would need to use `from apps.Visualize import something` Also, with your wsgi file, the `apps` directory would need to be in `/home/UserName/UserApp/`